# Cannot debug Angular application in WebStorm 2019.1

Tags: angular, webstorm

The latest version is supposed to work without the JetBrains IDE Support plugin for Chrome, yet it's just not working.

I have set the URL to `https://localhost:4200` in the "JavaScript Debug" run configuraiton, and after running

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --ssl --port 4200 --eval-source-map
```

, I run the debugger. A new Chrome instance gets created and the website gets displayed etc. However, no breakpoint gets hit.

Am I missing something?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--eval-source-map` option must be a culprit - it means to use the Webpack `eval` devtool as described in https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/, which does not include original source quality sourcemaps (see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12434#issuecomment-426593845).
If you open your app in Chrome Dev Tools, you will see that only the transpiled javascript  code is available at `webpack:///./src/app/app.component.ts` URLs.

Changing your start script to `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --ssl --port 4200` should help.

Comment: Omg all this pain. I struggled long enough to even *find* `--eval-source-map` because this is what I have to use to make the `ngx-logger` work properly. Otherwise it would not print module plus line numbers in the console. Now I had to learn that this option is not only deprecated, it also breaks the debugger. (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻ - but definitely thanks for that info. I removed it. It works now!